# How can I call golang struct field's function?

Tags: go, methods, struct, reflection

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type T struct{}

func (t *T) Foo() {
    fmt.Println("foo")
}

type A struct {
    Ts T
}

func main() {
    var t T
    var a A = A{Ts: t}
    val := reflect.ValueOf(&a).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
        vf := val.Field(i).Addr()
        fmt.Println(vf.Type())
        fmt.Println(vf.Kind())
        reflect.ValueOf(vf).MethodByName("Foo").Call([]reflect.Value{})
    }

}
```

> $ go run reflect_call_1.go
>   *main.T ptr panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Call on zero Value
>
> goroutine 1 [running]: reflect.flag.mustBe(0x0, 0x13)
>     /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:201 +0xae reflect.Value.Call(0x0,
>   0x0, 0x0, 0xc420049f00, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x40457c)
>     /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:300 +0x38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vf` is already of type [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value), you don't have to pass that to another [`reflect.ValueOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf) call.

Just call [`MethodByName()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.MethodByName) on `vf`:

```
vf.MethodByName("Foo").Call([]reflect.Value{})
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WugJ1p-OYEu)):

```
*main.T
ptr
foo
```